# Read data from excel columns with Ruby and Capybara

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, capybara

I'm having a logic problem to read the information of each excel column.

Each information i need is in separate columns totaling 58 columns. each information in this is compared with a field on the screen. My problem is the following: If all the information is in a single column I can read the rows vertically, but as the spreadsheet was formatted to be read horizontally due to a number of factors, I am not able to compare the values.

```
 Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
  book = Spreadsheet.open('c:/temp/gab_full.xls', "r")
  sheet = book.worksheet 0
  xls_offset = 1
  row_offset = 2
  sheet.each_with_index(xls_offset) do |row, idx|
  expected_tooltip = sheet.rows[1][3..58] # <-- here is the problem
  break if row[1].nil?
  expect(page).to have_css("tr.tvRow:nth-child(#{row_offset+idx}) .tvCell:nth-child(6) img[tooltip='#{expected_tooltip}']") **//Compares each image on the page with the information in each column of the worksheet.**
 end
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: If you've read in the whole spreadsheet, what's to stop you from indexing the various cells and reading values as you see fit? `each_with_index` is just one way to work through the data.

Comment: Just what I wanted to know, do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Index `sheet` directly, presumably, as per the [guide](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/blob/master/GUIDE.md): `sheet[x,y]` gives  you an arbitrary cell.

Comment: myn problem is here  expected_tooltip = sheet.rows[1][3..58]  i need read one by one

Comment: Slap on `.each` then, or `(3..58).each { |n| ... sheet.rows[1][n] }`.

Comment: Friend I'm struggling to solve this, if you can help me I'll give you a gift..lol

Comment: how to adjust this code please i don't know programming very well.

Comment: Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
  book = Spreadsheet.open('c:/temp/gab_full.xls', "r")
  sheet = book.worksheet 0
  xls_offset = 1
  row_offset = 2
  sheet.each_with_index(xls_offset) do |row, idx|
  pp expected_tooltip = sheet.rows[1][3..58].each 
  
  break if row[1].nil?
  expect(page).to have_css("tr.tvRow:nth-child(#{row_offset+idx}) .tvCell:nth-child(6) img[tooltip='#{expected_tooltip}']")

Comment: let it be!! 
I've seen that you don't know or don't like to help